# how to zoom the background-image in ie8 with css

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

i use a span with css style like this:

```
background: url("../../../Images/BasicIcons/Community_32.png") no-repeat scroll left center / 75% auto transparent;
```

it can zoom picture in firefox,chrome,ie9+ very well,but ie8 cannot,how to do it in ie8,who knows,please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you're combining it all into a single shorthand `background` style, the feature you're using for this is `background-size`.

Before we start tackling the IE8 question, it's worth noting an additional compatibility problem with Safari that you don't seem to have noticed yet -- although Safari supports `background-size`, it does has issues with it when used in the shorthand `background` style, as you've done it in the code in the question. If you want to support Safari, you'll be better off separating the `background-size` bit into its own separate line of code.

Now onto the actual question, about IE8 support.

Unfortuantely for you, IE8 does not support this feature at all. It's a relatively new addition to CSS, and wasn't even thought of when IE8 was released.

The only way you'll get it working in IE8 is to use a polyfill script; ie a small bit of Javascript that hacks the browser to add the missing feature.

The only polyfill I know of for `background-size` is [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/). Give it a go; it's fairly easy to set up, and should get things working for you. As a bonus, it also adds several other CSS3 features to old IE versions as well, so it may help you with a few other things too.

Hope that helps.